# AMQP pollable channel not recognised as pollable

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

My Spring Integration flow is defined in xml as per below (note that I have removed the opening/closing characters as the xml was not displaying correctly in my question):

```
<int-amqp:channel id="actionInstructionTransformed" message-driven="false"/>

<int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer
        input-channel="actionInstructionXmlValid" output-channel="actionInstructionTransformed"
        unmarshaller="actionInstructionMarshaller" />
```

I have got a poller defined with:

```
<int:poller id="customPoller" default="true" trigger="customPeriodicTrigger" task-executor="customTaskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="${poller.maxMessagesPerPoll}" error-channel="drsGatewayPollerError" />
    <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</int:poller>
```

In Java, I have got my consumer defined with:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true, value = "transactionManager")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "actionInstructionTransformed", poller = @Poller(value = "customPoller"),
      adviceChain = "actionInstructionRetryAdvice")
public final void processInstruction(final ActionInstruction instruction)
```

From the documentation (http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html), I understand that actionInstructionTransformed should be pollable as I have added message-driven="false".

When running my Spring Boot app, I am getting the exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A '@Poller' should not be specified for Annotation-based endpoint, since 'actionInstructionTransformed' is a SubscribableChannel (not pollable).

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE.

How can I force actionInstructionTransformed to be recognised as pollable?

Comment: There is a `code` formatting capabilities here in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. And only after that we'll come back to you with the help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not importing the XML? In that case, the framework will create a `DirectChannel` for the service activator input channel.

This works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("context.xml")
public class So42209741Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So42209741Application.class, args);
        context.getBean("pollable", MessageChannel.class).send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.close();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pollable", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public void foo(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd">


    <int-amqp:channel id="pollable" message-driven="false" />

</beans>
```

Comment: I trimmed down my Spring Boot app to the bear minimum (https://github.com/pilif42/amqpPollableChannel) and I figured out why it is broken in my case. If I use the exact same context.xml than you, that is all good. Now, in my context.xml, I add the following line <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${rabbitmq.host}" />. I rebuild, run and I get the exception:  A '@Poller' should not be specified for Annotation-based ...Why is this please? Note that I also commented out all my other Rabbit-specific configurations: queues and exchanges defined in xml.

Comment: Interesting; I get the same result by adding that bean to my context; for some reason it looks like the xml is not parsed. Investigating...

Comment: I have now found the solution: I still have <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${rabbitmq.host}" /> . And with <int-amqp:channel id="pollableChannel" message-driven="false" connection-factory="connectionFactory" /> , it now works.

Comment: Yeah - I just found the same solution - I need to track down why though :(

Comment: Good luck to figure out the real reason. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Another workaround is `<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" host="${spring.rabbitmq.host}" />` since that's the default bean we look for - still not sure why; something is eating the exception.

Comment: I found the bug; the auto-creation of the channel for the service activator kicks in if no matching bean is found in the context. Since the connection factory is not found, the main bean creation fails and the bean is removed; the bean post processor then goes ahead and creates a `DirectChannel`. I opened [INT-4228](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4228).